# Match a concatenated field to a list of variables

Tags: sql, oracle, keyword-search

Good Afternoon,

I'm trying to match a list of address fields (concatenated to give value ALL_ADDRESS) to a separate table that contains Suffixes, potentially hundreds of rows long.

my desired output is to show those entries where suffixes are part of the ALL_address variable (i.e PARIS STREET)

this works fine when I concatenate without a join, but when I begin to join I get an error:

```
select   s.suffix,
          x.key,
          x.B_ADDR1_TX,
          x.B_ADDR2_TX,
          x.B_ADDR3_TX, 
          x.b_addr_city,
          x.b_addr_postcd,
          x.b_addr_cntry,
          x.b_addr_state_cd,

         x.B_ADDR1_TX || ' ' || x.B_ADDR2_TX || ' ' || x.B_ADDR3_TX || ' ' || x.b_addr_city || ' ' || x.b_addr_postcd || ' ' || x.b_addr_cntry || ' ' || x.b_addr_state_cd as All_Address

          from test_table AS x

JOIN suffix_list AS s 

WHERE 

x.All_Address LIKE CONCAT('%',s.suffix,'%') ;
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  But proper syntax requires an `on` clause for a `join`:

```
from test_table x join
     suffix_list s 
     on x.All_Address LIKE CONCAT('%', s.suffix, '%')
```

As I recall, Oracle doesn't support `as` for table aliases, so your query might have other syntax problems as well.

In Oracle, this would more typically be written as:

```
from test_table x join
     suffix_list s 
     on x.All_Address LIKE '%' || s.suffix || '%'
```

Comment: apologies, switching between SQL and Oracle connections (long story) after removing AS this still does not work. also I agree it should be ON, however both ways can be used

Answer (score 0):

Haven't  been using Oracle for a while but:

```
CREATE table t1 (
 a varchar(5),
 b varchar(5),
 c varchar(5));
 INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('one','two','three');
 INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('two','nine','five');
 INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('two','one','one');

  CREATE TABLE t2 (filter varchar(5));
  INSERT INTO t2 VALUES ('one');
  INSERT INTO t2 VALUES ('six');


  WITH t1new AS (SELECT t1.*, a || ' ' || b || ' ' || c as address  FROM t1) 

  SELECT t1new.*
  FROM t1new,t2
  WHERE address like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', t2.filter),'%')
```

Above example runs in liveql Oracle.

Comment: like your style, but still the same error im afraid: ParseException line 13:37 cannot recognize input near '|' '' '' '|' in expression ....

Comment: I also tried your example in HUE Hive as I wondered if it was an Oracle thing but I also got the same message as I did for mine and yours in Oracle: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:31 cannot recognize input near '|' '' '' '|' in expression specification